# Bind event to key of Observable<JSON>

Tags: swift, uitableview, observable, rx-swift, swifty-json

I have a function that returns 2 observable events, the first one having a key, `athletes`, that i would like to create a table from. How can I achieve this?

Possible errors I get are:

- `Cannot subscript a value of incorrect or ambiguous type`
- `Value of type 'JSON' has no member 'asObservable'`

  ```
  self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
  teamRequest(schoolID: self.schoolID).debug("val").elementAt(1)
      .bind(to: self.tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "cell", cellType: UITableViewCell.self)) { row, element, cell in
      cell.textLabel?.text = element["Name"]
  }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
  ```

where teamRequest returns an observable of type JSON, emitting 2 values.

Comment: What is type 'JSON', exactly?
What does 'teamRequest(schoolID: self.schoolID)' return?

Answer (score 1):

In order for the code you posted to work, `teamRequest(schoolID: self.schoolID)` has to be returning an array. Does it do that?

I'm not sure what you think you are doing with the `elementAt` operator in there. That's an extraordinarily rare operator to need in typical RxSwift code. Are you sure you need it?

Answer (score 0):

Binding to table is only possible for observables of array type (i.e. 'Observable<[T]>').
If you need to select from an observable by key, use '.groupBy()' operator.